# Autocompletion of tags in orgmode

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

Is it possible to have in the completion window the list of ALL tags ?

`TAG1` + `TAG2` + `TAG3` + `TAG4`+ `TAG5`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org-tag-alist` is the global value that a file specific `#+TAGS:` specification *overrides*. You can do what you want by specifying the tags you want to add to `org-tag-persistent-alist`, whose value is *augmented* by a `#+TAGS:` spec.

Note BTW, that both of these are supposed to be [alists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html#Association-Lists) so the correct specification is:

```el
(setq org-tag-persistent-alist '(("TAG1") ("TAG2") ("TAG3")))
```

You can disable the persistent tags in a particular file by specifying:

```
#+STARTUP: noptag
```

See the doc string of the variable with `C-h v org-tag-persistent-alist RET` (and similarly for the other variable).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will read it carefully